# How to find doubles in master-child table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with a query to find doubles. Let met explain the situation by example:

**tableA** (the master table) has a key field `keyA` with these values :

```
keyA  
1  
2  
3  
etc
```

**tableB** (the client table) has a foreign key field `keyA` and a value field, `fieldB`

```
keyA  fieldB  
1     a  
1     b  
2     a  
2     b  
3     a  
3     c  
4     a  
4     b  
4     c  
etc
```

So, the values for `fieldB` in child table **tableB** are:

- for `tableA.keyA = 1` are: **a** and **b**
- for `tableA.keyA = 2` are: **a** and **b**
- for `tableA.keyA = 3` are: **a** and **c**
- for `tableA.keyA = 4` are: **a**, **b** and **c**

Now, given a value for `keyA` I need to find all records in **tableA** that have matching records in **tableB** for the field `fieldB`.

For example, if I search with `keyA = 1` then

- `tableA.keyA = 2` is OK because both have same `tableB.fieldB` (**a** and **b** versus **a** and **b**)
- `tableA.keyA = 3` is not OK because both have not same `tableB.fieldB` (**a** and **b** versus **a** and **c**)
- `tableA.keyA = 4` is not OK because both have not same `tableB.fieldB` (**a** and **b** versus **a**, **b** and **c**)

I need a query that can give me this result. I hope someone can help me with this or can point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple query , hope this will solve your problem

```
DECLARE @vkey int = 1
;WITH cte_test AS ( 
SELECT keyA,(SELECT ','+fieldb FROM tableB t1 WHERE t1.keyA = t.keyA FOR XML path('')) AS rslt
from   tableB t
GROUP BY t.keyA)
SELECT  t2.*
FROM    cte_test t1
    INNER JOIN cte_test t2 ON t1.[rslt] = t2.[rslt] AND t2.[keyA] <> t1.[keyA]
WHERE   t1.[keyA] = @vkey
```

If there is no other item have the same combination , then there is no records in the result, otherwise it will return the matched items.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no duplicates, you can do this with a self-join and aggregation:

```
select c.keyA, c2.keyA
from (select c.*, count(*) over (partition by keyA) as numBs
      from clientTable c
     ) c join
     (select c.*, count(*) over (partition by keyA) as numBs
      from clientTable c
     ) c2
     on c2.fieldB = c.fieldB and
        c2.keyA <> c.keyA and
        c.keyA = 1  -- or whatever key you want to check
where c.numBs = c2.numBs
group by c.keyA, c2.keyA, c.numBs, c2.numBs
having count(*) = c.numBs;
```

The idea is to count the number of `fieldB` values for each `keyA`.  These need to be equal (`where c.numBs = c2.numBs`) and to check that all match (`having count(*) = c.numBs`).

Comment: Assuming there are no duplicates, well it is possible that more records in tableA have same childrecords in tableB, is that a problem with this solution ? or what did you mean

Comment: I cant get this query to compile, I changed bc* to bc.* and changed clientTable to tableB but now I get error that alias b2 is unknown

Comment: i mean alias bc is unknown

Comment: @GuidoG . . . There was a typo in the first subquery.